# Adjusting the ring inside accepting state, tikz's automata library

Tags: tikz-arrows, automata

Long story short, I have decided to make my LaTeX documents needlessly pretty. I achieved this by using `\xcolor` to define nord colors then used `\color` and `\pagecolor` to adjust the colors of the whole document. Only one slight problem, it clashes with my automata library in a minor way:

[image]

The Accepting state is a bit hard to make out. I am trying to solve this by either filling the area between the ring and circle with nord2 *or* increase the distance between them so it won't be so confusing. But I am not sure how to do either.

[Nord theme colors for reference](https://www.nordtheme.com/docs/colors-and-palettes)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\tikzset{
->,  % makes the edges directed
>=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick, fill=nord1}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
every edge/.append style={thick, font=\footnotesize},
initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
auto,
}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{nord0}{HTML}{2E3440}
 \definecolor{nord1}{HTML}{3B4252}
  \definecolor{nord4}{HTML}{D8DEE9}
 
  \usepackage{pagecolor}
  \begin{document}
 
  \color{nord4}
  \pagecolor{nord0}
 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [state,accepting ] (1) {4};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

The answer was in using in `double =nord1`, big thanks to zarko.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: Can you provide a minimal example ?

Comment: Does this qualify as minimal example?

Comment: yes, it is qualified as a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, 
                positioning}
\tikzset{
>=Stealth, % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={color=nord4, thick, fill=nord1}, 
every  edge/.append style={color=nord4,->, thick, font=\footnotesize},
initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
auto,
}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{nord0}{HTML}{2E3440}
\definecolor{nord1}{HTML}{3B4252}
\definecolor{nord4}{HTML}{D8DEE9}

\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{nord0}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [state,accepting, double=nord4] (1) {4}; % <---
% added for test
\node [state,right=of 1] (2)  {1};
\path(1) edge["$a$"]   (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or you may prefer:

[image]

for this image you need to replace  `double=nord4` with  `semithick, double=nord4`. With `semithick` the thickness of the white line node borders is reduced that the color between them is better visible. If you not like to have thinner white lines, you simply delete this option.

Comment: That is what I had in mind yes, but I thought adding distance between them would allow for nord1 stand out. It is pure white. Is there any way to fill that space with nord1?

Comment: @CrimsonCrusader, sorry, but I don't understand what you like to change or add. In accepting state the border line is now in now is double=nord4, do you like to have in the same color as is background? if this is the case, just replace `double=nord4` with `semithick, double=nord0`.

Comment: @CrimsonCrusader, see edited answer.